# Upload file data from input of type file in a form using javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, forms, upload

I have a from with input of type file I need to get the file data from this form without refreshing the page 
I'm try to use this function

```
function submitForm(form){
  var url = $(form).attr("action");
  var formData = {};
  $(form).find("input[name]").each(function (index, node) {
     formData[node.name] = node.value;
  });
  $.post(url, formData).done(function (data) {
     alert(data);
  }); 
}
```

but this function get the values of form inputs, but I need to get all file data (tmp_name, file_name, file_type ...)
so can any one help me in this please
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can reference your input of type file by id and then get the `files` property to obtain information about the files.
Then you can loop through the files and for example read the `name`, `size` and `type` attribute of the File object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

For example

```js
$("#theForm").submit(function(e) {
  submitForm(this);
  e.preventDefault();
});

function submitForm(form) {
  var url = $(form).attr("action");
  var formData = {};
  formData.filesInfo = [];
  var files = $('#inputFile').prop("files");

  $(files).each(function() {
    var fileInfo = {};
    fileInfo.name = this.name;
    fileInfo.size = this.size;
    fileInfo.type = this.type;
    formData.filesInfo.push(fileInfo);
  });

  $.post(url, formData).done(function (data) {
    alert(data);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="theForm">
    <input type="file" id="inputFile">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I tried to use the "files" but the page refreshed automatically

Comment: When did the page refresh automatically? Did you press a submit button?
In the example above I used a form `<form id="theForm">` Do you use a different id?

Comment: The fourth bird thanks a lot "prop()" method solved the problem thank you very much :)

Comment: @MohamedSalah Nice! :) You are welcome. If this solved your problem, maybe you can consider marking the answer as accepted.